# How do I output to monitor from android device

Tags: android, video

I am trying to do a demo on a android device, but the screen is too small so is kinda hard to do a demo let say in a meeting room with 12 people. Although I can pass the device around the table or just simple borrow or get more devices for the demo purposes.

I understand there are devies where you can buy special USB converter to do TV-out like in iPhone, and some specific devices on Android (e.g. Motorola Incredible?) But I have to demo on a specific device where it runs standard Android build.

I understand I can do it on Android emulator but the screen refresh rate is too slow, as it will send the wrong message to the audience that the app is slow. (Or there is a way to increase the screen refresh rate for emulator?) Furthermore the emulator doesn't support multitouch. (Or am I wrong?)

Not sure if anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have many options.

You can use [Droid@Screen](http://codaset.com/jens-riboe/droidatscreen/wiki), but the refresh rate on it is maybe 6fps. I am not aware of any other software projector that is faster.

You failed to mention the "specific device" that you are using, so I cannot comment on whether it has TV-out capability. The HTC DROID Incredible and the Samsung Galaxy S series support composite output -- I use the DROID Incredible for this purpose a fair bit. Most of the devices that have HDMI output only support it for certain built-in apps, such as the video player.

You can rent or purchase a device projector, like an [ELMO](http://www.elmousa.com/index.php). These are fairly expensive pieces of equipment purchased new, though I see a handful of used ones on eBay at interesting prices (though watch out -- many seem to lack the AC adapter).

If you can delay the demo several months, you may be able to use a Google TV.

And that's about it, AFAIK.

> Or there is a way to increase the screen refresh rate for emulator?

Get a faster computer.

> Furthermore the emulator doesn't support multitouch. (Or am I wrong?)

I am not aware of a way to simulate multitouch with an emulator, though I have not gone looking for a solution there.

Comment: Just an FYI, it seems only "some" versions of Galaxy S actually support cable out. Other versions (such as the one I got in Japan) have had this feature removed for mysterious (DRM?) reasons. Double check that yours has a menu option for doing so before buying cables.

Comment: I am using the new Viewpad and HTC Legend for the apps demo, I am hoping to seek alternative solutions and hopefully not force to buy those devices that has such capabilities. Thanks everyone :) I will check out Droid@Screen and not sure which one is the "device" projector from ELMO? I couldn't find it from their site.

Comment: +1 for the HTC incredible composite output tip - I totally forgot about that feature and should be using that!

Comment: @foresclown: http://elmousa.com/digital-visual-presenters.php and http://elmousa.com/analog-visual-presenters.php for the ELMO presenters.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Galaxy S3 Android mobile phone, you can use [Mobizen](http://www.mobizen.com/en/). It's free and the screen refresh rate is relatively good. You can control you mobile phone from you computer using your mouse and your keyboard. It's working using USB, 3G or Wifi connection.

Comment: I ended up using this, but you don't need a Galaxy S3 just to use it. I successfully installed and used this on a Galaxy Nexus also.

Comment: Mobizen mirrors VERY fast compared to other java tools I've tried.

Comment: I also tried Mobizen with an LG Nexus 5. Indeed way faster than Droid@screen and Android Screen Monitor, which I found to be extremely slow

Comment: One issue I have found with it though is that their website help does not reflect what I see in my app, using a Google Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this Android screencast tool: http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ in past demos, but again the downside is the relatively slow refresh rate.

Comment: Thanks :) I have tried that, I think their refresh rate is just 4fps and will try Droid@Screen and see if it makes any difference :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rooted device, you could try Droid VNC Server (it's on the market). The refresh rate isn't ***too*** bad, but I certainly wouldn't want to demo full motion video or an arcade game on it.

You could also get a webcam, rig it up with a tripod. Something like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tripod-Meets-Logitech-Webcam/). Downside is your hands will be in the way, maybe issues with lighting and/or focus. Upside is a decent refresh rate.

Comment: Thanks sir! I will check out Droid VNC, hopefully is not too hard to setup the VNC server.

Comment: Too bad we need to do video demo as well :( but thanks for the advise!